# Could Not create ssl/tls secure channel. Html Agility

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape a site using HTML Agility Pack. The site is using https and it shows the error on this line

```
doc = web.Load(url);
```

**I am creating a desktop application not a web application.**

Comment: Adding the url (or a url with a similar error if you cannot provide the one you use) will probably help people to try it and see the error on their side.

Comment: https://www.manta.com/c/mtxbllz/berbere-world-imports-inc
Sorry here is the url

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable the correct protocol type on the service point manager. Just add it before the line you said caused the error. This should do it.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
doc = web.Load(url);
```